# Cold backup database, what files to copy, slow shutdown?

Tags: backup

After [a broken server installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458826/ssh-update-to-14-04-the-disk-drive-for-is-not-ready-yet-or-not-present) I am going to backup a mysql database with a cold backup. This is, because I am not able to dump the sql tables and somehow everything is broken. My questions are at the bottom of this post.

```
$ tail /var/log/mysql/error.log
140511  0:23:35 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
140511  0:23:35 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
140511  0:23:35 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Cannot assign requested address
140511  0:23:35 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
140511  0:23:35 [ERROR] Aborting

140511  0:23:35  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
140511  0:23:36  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 16358534
140511  0:23:36 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

and

```
netstat -lp | grep 3306
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
```

gives no output, an so on and so forth..

However, following the [cold backups section here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-backup-excerpt/5.6/en/innodb-backup.html), I have to

```
1. Do a slow shutdown of the MySQL server and make sure that it stops without errors.
2. Copy all InnoDB data files (ibdata files and .ibd files) into a safe place.
3. Copy all the .frm files for InnoDB tables to a safe place.
4. Copy all InnoDB log files (ib_logfile files) to a safe place.
5. Copy your my.cnf configuration file or files to a safe place.
```

1. How do I find out if my database was shutdown slowly? What may happen if I do the other steps and it did not get a cold shutdown?
2. Is there any chance to find out, whats the meaning of "all"? In /var/lib/mysql I find one ibdata1 file,
3. in /var/lib/mysql/ e.g. wordpress/ I find several .frm files,
4. There are two ib_lofiles in /var/lib/mysql, and
5. in /etc/mysql/ is one my.cnf file.